# Method cannot handle event "KeyDown because they do not have a compatible signature"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, keydown

So I'm trying to make a program which detects when I key is pressed *down* and assigns the value of said to a variable and then outputs it in a message box, however I cannot do this because of the follow error:

**Method 'Main_KeyDown' cannot handle event 'KeyDown' because they do not have a compatible signature.**

I am not sure why this is or why this is happening, it does not throw an error when I use the KeyPress event, but does also happen why I try to use KeyUp - however for this program I need it to work with KeyDown.

Here is the code in question:

```
Private Sub Main_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    _keyDown = e.KeyChar
    MsgBox(_keyDown)
End Sub
```

I am very lost for ideas here, never come across this error before, i've tried Googling and looking at other Overflow posts but none of them helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method is not valid for a KeyDown event because the signature of that event (and KeyUp also) is different from the signature of KeyPress

Use instead

```
Private Sub Main_KeyDown(sender As Object,e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
```

Look here for the [differences between KeyDown, KeyPress and KeyUp](http://Difference%20between%20the%20KeyDown%20Event,%20KeyPress%20Event%20and%20KeyUp%20Event%20in%20Visual%20Studio)